# How to handel tooltip in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

[Tooltip image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPojh.png)Not able to handle tooltip with getAttribute and getText in selenium java.
Below is the code

**HTML :**

```
<span class="exclude-syndicated-hint hint--top" data-hint="Programs like 
&quot;The Today Show&quot; are often syndicated across major networks and 
play on a variety of channels. Checking this box will only give you a 
single copy of the program.">
<i class="syndicated-hint-icon fa fa-info-circle"></i>                                   
</span>
```

**JAVA :**

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//i[@class='syndicated-hint-icon fa fa-info-circle']") 
public WebElement tooltip; 
public String settooltip() 
{ 
    Actions a = new Actions(driver); 
    a.moveToElement(tooltip).perform(); 
    String actualTooltip = tooltip.getAttribute("data-hint"); 
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your java code..

Comment: @FindBy(xpath = "//i[@class='syndicated-hint-icon fa fa-info-circle']")
    public WebElement tooltip; 
 
 public String settooltip() {
        
        Actions a = new Actions(driver);
        a.moveToElement(tooltip).perform();
 String actualTooltip = tooltip.getAttribute("data-hint");
  }

Comment: Are you using Page Objects with Page Factory?

Comment: @DebanjanB yes using page objects with page factory

Answer (score 3):

```
 // Create action class object
Actions builder=new Actions(driver);

// find the tooltip xpath
WebElement _tooltip=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='exclude-syndicated-hint hint--top']));


// Mouse hover to that text message
builder.moveToElement(_tooltip).perform();


// Extract text from tooltip
 String tooltip_msg=_tooltip.getAttribute("data-hint");


 // Print the tooltip message just for our refrences
 System.out.println("Tooltip message is "+tooltip_msg);
```

Comment: I tried the above code but got an error like "org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//@class['exclude-syndicated-hint hint--top']" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element."

Comment: I update xpath it's by mistake written wrong now you can try it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy help, I was using the wrong XPath (copied from selenium IDE)

Comment: `soni I tried but not have enough reputation for the upvote

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

You need to call `perform()` on `Actions` class methods.

First we need to create new **action builder instance** by passing the **webdriver** instance.

Read more about [moveToElement](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)

For more information about mouse hover actions read [this](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-perform-mouseover-action-in-selenium-webdriver)

```
Actions toolAct = new Actions(driver);
toolAct.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
WebElement toolTipElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='exclude-syndicated-hint hint--top']));
String toolTipText = toolTipElement.getText();
System.out.println("tooltip :- "+toolTipText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in parts:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//i[@class='syndicated-hint-icon fa fa-info-circle']") 
public WebElement tooltip;
```

Is finding the

```html
<i class="syndicated-hint-icon fa fa-info-circle"></i>
```

Which doesn't have the attribute "data-hint".
But you still try to get the attribute from it.

```
String actualTooltip = tooltip.getAttribute("data-hint");
```

First things first, if you want to get this value, you don't even need to hover it, hover the element itself and get the attribute value is not really "testing (not the right word to use here)" the tooltip thing.

But thinking from the point that you still want to hover it, you can do like this:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "LOCATOR FOR THE <span> AND NOT THE <i>") 
public WebElement tooltip;

public String getTooltipMessage() {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
    action.moveToElement(tooltip).build().perform(); 
    String actualTooltip = tooltip.getAttribute("data-hint"); 
}
```

case you just want to get the message

```
@FindBy(xpath = "LOCATOR FOR THE <span> AND NOT THE <i>") 
public WebElement tooltip;

public String getTooltipMessage() {
    String actualTooltip = tooltip.getAttribute("data-hint"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try below css selector**

```
@FindBy(css = "span[class='exclude-syndicated-hint.hint--top']");
```

**or**

```
 @FindBy(css = "i[class='syndicated-hint-icon.fa.fa-info-circle']");
```